# replace ^M(control M character) in a text file in python

Tags: python, string, control-characters

The file is like this:

```
This line has control character ^M this is bad
I will try it
```

I want to remove control M characters in the file, and create a new file like this using Python

```
This line has control character  this is bad
I will try it
```

I tried couple of approaches below:

```
line.replace("\r", "")
```

and

```
line.replace("\r\n", "")
```

Here is part of the code snippet:

```
with open(file_path, "r") as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()

new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    new_line = line.replace("\r", "")
    new_lines.append(new_line)

new_file_name = "replace_control_char.dat"
new_file_path = os.path.join(here, data_dir, new_file_name)
with open(new_file_path, "w") as output_file:
    for line in new_lines:
        output_file.write(line)
```

However,  the new file I got is:

```
This line has control character
 this is bad
I will try it
```

"This line has control character" and " this is bad" are not on the same line. I expect remove control M character will make these two phrases on the same line.
Can someone help me solve this issue?

Thanks,
Arthur

Comment: this is a windows only issue right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: It'd be the same on Unix, because of Python's universal newline handling.

Comment: how to find control M character in Python?
i used re.match(rb"\r", string),  and it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rely on text mode in that case.

On Windows understands sole `\r` as linefeeds (even if the "official" line terminator is `\r\n`) and on Macintosh, the line terminator can be only `\r`. Text mode converts linefeeds as `\n` or remove them if followed by `\n`, so it destroys the information you need.

Universal newlines by default makes this code also fail on Unix/Linux. Python [behaves the same on all platforms](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open)

> Python doesn’t depend on the underlying operating system’s notion of text files; all the the processing is done by Python itself, and is therefore platform-independent.

If you want to remove those, you have to use binary mode.

```
with open(file_path, "rb") as input_file:
    contents = input_file.read().replace(b"\r",b"")
with open(file_path, "wb") as output_file:
    output_file.write(contents)
```

That code will remove *all* `\r` characters (including line terminators). That works but if your aim is just to remove stray `\r` and preserve endlines, another method is required.

One way to do it is to use a regular expression, which can accept binary (`bytes`) as well:

```
re.sub(rb"\r([^\n])",rb"\1",contents)
```

That regular expression removes `\r` chars only if not followed by `\n` chars, efficiently preserving CR+LF windows end-of-line sequences.

Comment: I ran it in Mac system,  and faced this issue.  So in text file mode (on mac or unix),  does it understand \r as linefeeds too?  I tried your solution, it works.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: Nice thorough answer, I like it.

Comment: thanks. Those newlines issues are hell for most people.

Comment: Those newline issues are hell in both directions: while the Python file reader is universal, the Python file writer uses the OS's preferred newline by default in text mode, so running the same code to write a file on Linux and windows will give you different line endings unless you're careful to specify the line ends you want.

Comment: wait until you track the files with git which changes (or not) LF into CR LF in the repositories :)